# Prove the quadratic approximation

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a function with a second derivative $f''(x)$. Prove that $$f(x+\Delta x) = f(x) + f'(x)\Delta x + O(|\Delta x|^2),$$ as $\Delta x$ approaches $0$.

So I wasn't quite sure about this one since I thought for this to occur we will need to have  $f''(x)\Delta x^2/2$ on the right side, but the question tells us to prove this. Could someone help me what should I do for this?

Comment: It cannot be as you said unless $f$ is a quadratic polynomial because there is a precise equality sign. I recall MVT being important.

Comment: @CalvinKhor: what do you mean ? The $O$ breaks the equality.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, in the paragraph under the question statement, the OP said "we will need to have $f''(x)\Delta x^2/2$" which I understood as replacing the O(...). Maybe I misunderstood

Comment: It might help you as you think about this to switch the variables: replace $x$ with $a$. then you can use $x$ for $\Delta x$, or maybe use $h$ for that instead. The point is to avoid thinking of $x$ as something that varies, and instead think of it as a fixed point. Since $f''(a)$ exists, there is a constant $M$ and some $\delta> 0$ such that if $|h| < \delta$, then$$\left |\dfrac{f'(a+h) - f'(a)}h\right| < M$$ Also note that for $f''(a)$ to be defined, $f'$ must exist in some neighborhood of $a$.